# Fill a javascript array from a php multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying to fill a javascript array from a php multidimensional array.

I've used the following code to convert the php array to a javascript array:

```
var bookings = <?php echo json_encode( $bookeddates ) ?>;
```

The code that's working:

```
var unavailableDates = [
        {start: bookings[0][1], end: bookings[0][2]},
        {start: bookings[1][1], end: bookings[1][2]},
];
```

The code that's not working:

```
var unavailableDates = [
        for (var i = 0; i < bookings.length; i++) {
            {start: bookings[i][1], end: bookings[i][2]},
        }
];
```

The solution is very simple I guess but I'm struggling with this problem for days already.
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a for loop inside an JS array notation - first create the array and then fill it.

```
var unavailableDates = [];
for (var i = 0; i < bookings.length; i++) {
    unavailableDates.push({start: bookings[i][1], end: bookings[i][2]});
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push